# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'; cuando intento ejecutar archivo python

Tags: numpy, python-3.7, tensorflow

Tengo las siguientes versiones instaladas:
Python 3.8.10
TensorFlow: 2.11.0

Sin embargo, al momento que ejecuto el archivo principal del proyecto que descargué de github => https://github.com/thiagosantos1/CNN_Find_Glasses; me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

<module 'tensorflow._api.v2.version' from 'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\version\**init**.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cnn_glasses.py", line 273, in 
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'**

*Estuve investigando y al parece se debe a que a partir de la Versión 2 de Tensor ya no maneja esos atributos. Sin embargo, agregué el comando: tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution(); que se menciona agregar cuando se usa la versión 2 de TensorFlow; pero me muestra el Error que menciono líneas arriba.

**Gracias por su apoyo.**

Comment: El link que proporcionas da error 404 (Page not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El repositorio es de hace 4 años, por que que te aconsejo crear un entorno virtual de Python con alguna versión de TensorFlow 1.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Una vez que tengas virtualenv instalado, puedes crear un nuevo entorno virtual para TensorFlow 1.x con el siguiente comando:

```
virtualenv -p python3 tensorflow1
```

Este comando creará un nuevo entorno virtual llamado tensorflow1 que se basa en Python 3.x. Una vez que se haya creado el entorno virtual, puedes activarlo con el siguiente comando:

```
source tensorflow1/bin/activate
```

En Windows, puedes activar el entorno virtual con el siguiente comando en lugar:

```
tensorflow1\Scripts\activate
```

Una vez que hayas activado el entorno virtual, puedes instalar la versión 1.x de TensorFlow con el siguiente comando:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.x
```

Reemplaza x con la versión específica de TensorFlow 1.x que deseas instalar. Una vez que hayas instalado TensorFlow en el entorno virtual, ya puedes comenzar a utilizarlo para ejecutar el código que necesites.

En la [página de lanzamiento de versiones de TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases) podrás buscar que versión había en la fecha de publicación del repositorio. Es posible que también debas utilizar otra versión de Python.

Comment: Excelente Cristian. Muy valioso aporte. Gracias¡¡¡

Comment: Mi recomendacion es buscar una alternativa a ese reposotorio. Los downgrades no son buenos.